# -webkit-tap-highlight-color not applied to area tag

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, mobile-webkit

Ok, I know this has been asked many times, but my situation is a bit different:

I have an image map and I don't want Android/iPhone to display the green border (gray overlay on iPhone) when an AREA on the image is tapped.

I have tried `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)`
and it seems to work for an `<a>` link but not an `<area>`. I guess the problem is that in fact no CSS can be applied to `<area>`?

Can this somehow be circumvented? I don't want the user to see the green border when he taps on an area.

Comment: _I guess the problem is that in fact no CSS can be applied to <area>?_ Very possibly. I'm not sure, if there are workarounds other than getting rid of `area` element. Maybe you can try replacing it with transparent SVG image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, browsers doesn't allow to set(and run) css properties to area tags.

I use maphilight plugin to do that in jquery, it works like a charm :
http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/

Example, here : http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html

Then, I guess that you could set transparent border with : `stroke: false`