# Removing heighlight from image map area in Android 4.x app via PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, css, cordova, imagemap, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have tried every which way to try to remove the heighlight when pushing on an image map area of an image. I have search google time and time again and have added all the CSS code i could find in hopes it would help.. but it does not seem to.

An example of what i am talking about:
[image: android tablet]

I have added:

```
 -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only; 
 border:none; 
 outline: 0; 
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
 -khtml-user-select: none; 
 -o-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;

 * {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
cursor: none !important; 
-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
-khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
outline:none;
border: none;
 }

 img{
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
outline:none;
border: none;
border-style: none;
  }

 body, textarea:focus, input:focus, area:focus{
    outline:none;
    border: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}

a{
   outline:none !important;
   border: none !important;
}

a img
{
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}

area{
outline:none;
border: none;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
-khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}

#map {
outline:none;
border: none;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
-khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}

 <img height="1024" src="img/MM.png" usemap="#MM_map" width="768" hidefocus="true">
 <area coords="35,116,349,225" href="#HULU" id="HULU_id" onclick="$('#HULU').click();" shape="rect" style="border: none;" onfocus="blur();">
```

Comment: Try capturing onblur event & call e.preventDefault()? It works for some non-mobile browsers -don't have phone to test right now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880627/webkit-tap-highlight-color-not-applied-to-area-tag Try looking at this topic, might have a solution to your problem.

Comment: @StealthRT: did you find a solution for the problem? would you mind sharing?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could prevent that was by capturing the ontouchend event and preventing default browser behavior by returning false on the handler.

with jQuery:

```
$("map area").on("touchend", function() {
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way.  Proven.  Used this again, just now even, in Android cordova app.

```
img[usemap], map area {
     outline: none;
}
```

enjoy